# Should there be auth on communtity website?

Tags: django, html, github, oauth, vs-web-site-project

I'm enhancing the website architecture for an **open-source community**. I want to provide some options(or features) to ***authenticated users*** only because an open-source community always contains thousands of members which leads to a chance of *spamming*. I'm adding ***OAuth using GitHub*** which can prevent user spamming.

All I would like to know whether should I add OAuth on an open-source community website or not? Is it a good practice? or there is some another way I should do to prevent user-spam?

I want to prevent spamming, for example, user-2 can not update the profile of user-1 *(just an example don't want to achieve this task)*

Answer (score 1):

If you are not building an anon targeted website, then yes, user profiles are a need. If your website user flow suggests editing other user's profiles, you can allow it in django, but why? User profiles *usually* are only editable by owners.

Research what OAuth provider your users might prefer. [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) and similar apps give you a way to easily add OAuth of any of hundreds of providers, so it's only a question what your users want to use.

Comment: Ok I will do some research on requirements of users  thnx